# How to deserialize asp.net datetime as JSON datetime with client's timezone

Tags: json, angularjs, datetime, jsonserializer, asp.net-apicontroller

I'm struggling with datetimes a bit. I'm using asp.net mvc api controllers, a microsoft sql server and AngularJS.

On some button click I'm sending a JSON formatted date to an api-controller. When I post 2015-11-31 00:00 and I look in Fiddler to see what's really posted, I see that the date is formatted as such: 2015-11-30T23:00:00.000Z. (2015-11-31 - 1 hour UTC+01:00 Amsterdam, Berlin, Ber....) This is perfect because there might be a difference between the timezone the sql server might be in and the client. (Or is it?)

The problem is though: When I get the date back from the sql server it doesn't take the client's time zone into account. When I read the DateTime object from the sql server and I return it JSON formatted, the date that's being displayed is: 2015-11-30T23:00:00.000Z. I want it to add 1 hour to be in the timezone where the client is.

My question is: What do I do to get it to keep the timezone in to account while deserializing the JSON string that comes back from my api-controller?

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem turns out to be that when the object is being deserialized, the date property is *not of type DateTime*. It is of type string. Simply converting it to date by using new Date("2015-11-30T23:00:00.000Z") will do the trick.

I made filter for it:

```
.filter('from_gmt_to_local_date', [function () {
  return function (text) {
    return new Date(text);
  };
}])
```

Usage:

```
{{contract.StartDate | from_gmt_to_local_date | date:'dd-MM-yyyy'}}
```

Hope this helps anybody.