# Time format returned from JSON in angular.js app

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, momentjs

So I receive my app data via an API returning JSON data. With that, my time stamps are always returned with an undesirable look. Always like this:

> 2013-11-25T12:44:02

So I am using angular to build my app and couldn't see a way to format this with simply returning something like:

```
<div>
    <p ng-repeat="date in ppt.Alerts | filter:{type: DenialStatement}"><span>{{date.date}}<span> <span>{{date.descr}}<span></p>
</div>
```

In this case, **date** is that time property. So I was figuring within my html, if I could benefit from using moment.js to format this or a better way to do this across the board.

Can anyone here assist with this?

Thanks much.

Comment: can you just use the filter shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162443/how-to-deserialize-asp-net-datetime-as-json-datetime-with-clients-timezone)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your text is string representation of date object, you can assign 
 `date.date = new Date(input)`
 during data retrieval this will work fine. And you can print directly angular built in date filter

```
<span>{{date.date|date :'dd/MM/yyyy'}}<span>
```

or any format you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has built in date filter

```
{{date.date |  date : format : timezone}}
```

See [date filter docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) for format and timezone usage